# NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFConstantString sizeWithTextStyle:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x170838

Tags: ios, iphone, cocoa-touch, core-plot, linechart

Working on Line Chart using coreplot library. It throws Invalid Argument exception.
I have made the septate project and create xib file and I have connected that xib file with CPDScatterPlotViewController. It runs and works but when I tried to integrate with my project it throws exceptions.
Using this Code:

```
#import "CPDScatterPlotViewController.h"

@implementation CPDScatterPlotViewController

@synthesize hostView = hostView_;

-(id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil {
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

-(void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    // Releases the view if it doesn't have a superview.
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Release any cached data, images, etc that aren't in use.
}

#pragma mark - UIViewController lifecycle methods
-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];
    [self initPlot];
}

#pragma mark - Chart behavior
-(void)initPlot {
    [self configureHost];
    [self configureGraph];
    [self configurePlots];
    [self configureAxes];    
}

-(void)configureHost {  
    self.hostView = [(CPTGraphHostingView *) [CPTGraphHostingView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.bounds];
    self.hostView.allowPinchScaling = YES;    
    [self.view addSubview:self.hostView];    
}
```

The Error is occured on CPTMutableTextStyle while debugging.

```
 -(void)configureGraph {
        // 1 - Create the graph
        CPTGraph *graph = [[CPTXYGraph alloc] initWithFrame:self.hostView.bounds];
        [graph applyTheme:[CPTTheme themeNamed:kCPTDarkGradientTheme]];
        self.hostView.hostedGraph = graph;
        // 2 - Set graph title
        NSString *title = @"Portfolio Prices: April 2012";
        graph.title = title;  
        // 3 - Create and set text style
        CPTMutableTextStyle *titleStyle = [CPTMutableTextStyle textStyle];
        titleStyle.color = [CPTColor whiteColor];
        titleStyle.fontName = @"Helvetica-Bold";
        titleStyle.fontSize = 16.0f;
        graph.titleTextStyle = titleStyle;
        graph.titlePlotAreaFrameAnchor = CPTRectAnchorTop;
        graph.titleDisplacement = CGPointMake(0.0f, 10.0f);
        // 4 - Set padding for plot area
        [graph.plotAreaFrame setPaddingLeft:30.0f];    
        [graph.plotAreaFrame setPaddingBottom:30.0f];
        // 5 - Enable user interactions for plot space
        CPTXYPlotSpace *plotSpace = (CPTXYPlotSpace *) graph.defaultPlotSpace;
        plotSpace.allowsUserInteraction = YES; 
    }


    @end
```

Comment: Which line does it crash on?

Comment: Em sorry on this line:  graph.title = title;

Comment: try this link..this will help you http://docs.millennialmedia.com/iOS-SDK/iOSAddingLinkerFlag.html